# Как в диве с ограниченной шириной задать область видимости по умолчанию справа?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, адаптивность

Если див ограничить по ширине, и сделать пролистываемым внутри, то он по умолчанию сделает область видимости слева от содержимого. Как в примере. Каким образом можно сделать область видимости справа? Чтобы при этом оставался скролл и по возможности без применения js.

```css
div{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:auto;
  border:2px solid black;
}
img{
  height:170px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://arte1.ru/images/detailed/4/2219.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Я полагаю только scrollLeft задать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вероятное решение:

Зеркально переворачиваем div через `transform: scaleX(-1);` но картинка внутри зеркалится вместе с ним. Поэтому дополнительно добавляем еще одно "отзеркаливание" для картинки внутри.

```css
div{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:auto;
  border:2px solid black;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}
img{
  height:170px;
  transform: scaleX(-1)
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://arte1.ru/images/detailed/4/2219.jpg"/>
</div>
```

P.s. упс, найден косяк, если скроллить стрелками с клавиатуры, а не мышкой*

Чтобы наверняка, с JS это будет так (на случай, если таких элемемнтов много):

```js
(function(){

var scroll = document.querySelectorAll('.js-scroll');
var i;
for(i = 0; i < scroll.length; i++){
  scroll[i].scrollTo(100500, 0);
}

})();
```

```css
div{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:auto;
  border:2px solid black;
}
img{
  height:170px;
}
```

```html
<div class="js-scroll">
  <img src="https://arte1.ru/images/detailed/4/2219.jpg"/>
</div>
```